# Firebase - Dynamic or change orderByChild variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 ways I would like to sort my database table.

The first is by date or in my case `created`, and the second is by `score`.

So I have a dropdown where the user can specify which they'd like to sort by and I have a function which calls the correct database ref.

```
 goToNew() {
  this.postFeed = [];
  this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.location)
  .orderByChild('created')
  .startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)) //last 24hrs
  .limitToLast(10)
  .on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
  });
}

goToHot() {
  this.postFeed = [];
  this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.location)
  .orderByChild('score')
  .startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)) //last 24hrs
  .limitToLast(10)
  .on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
  });
}
```

I have 2 issues with this:

1. Switching between each `database.ref` causes memory leaks.. If you switch between the 2 settings a couple times and add a new post it shows the post several times.. which is weird
2. I'd prefer to just dynamically switch between the `orderByChild` since that is the only thing that is different..

Does anyone have a better solution for this that fixes my problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries are immutable. Once you create a query with a specific sort order, you cannot modify it. So there's no way to change the dynamically change the sort order on your query.

> Switching between each database.ref causes memory leaks.

It would be great if you could share how you determined this. But most likely it's because you're not removing the previous listener. You can [remove the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) by calling `off()` on the query:

```
let query = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.location)
    .orderByChild('created')
    .startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)) //last 24hrs
    .limitToLast(10);
query.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
});
```

And then:

```
query.off();
```

Or alternatively keep track of the listener:

```
var listener = query.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
});
```

And then:

```
query.off(listener);
```